# UITableViewCell loses highlighted selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using `[tableview reloadData];` to reload the data in my UItableView, however when I use this I loose my highlight on my UItableVewCell.

I would like to know the best way to reinstate this highlight.

I set a tempIndexPath when the user selects the cell they edit the information then I call reloadData, then inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I use this code to re-highlight the cell however its not working.

```
if ([tempIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        cell.selected = YES;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code keeps the highlighted selection, and is safe with resorting/inserts/repositioning since it keeps a reference to the underlying object from the model, instead of the index path. It also scrolls to the selection, which is helpful when the updated model causes the selection to be moved out of the current scroll position's frame.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Save the selected object at this row for maintaining the highlight later in reloadData
    _selectedItem = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (void) reloadData
{
    [_itemsTable reloadData];

    //Reselect and scroll to selection
    int numItems = _items.count;
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [_numItems objectAtIndex:i];
        if (dict == _selectedItem) {
            //This is more reliable than calling the indexPathForSelectedRow on the UITableView,
            //  since the selection is cleared after calling reloadData
            NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            [_itemsTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
            [_itemsTable selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:FALSE scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the selected row, reload your table view's data and select the row again.

```
NSIndexPath* selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
[tableView reloadData];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

You should know that this is dangerous, because if new items were added to the table view before the selected row, the selection will not be the correct cell. You should calculate how many rows were inserted before the row and adjust the `selectedIndexPath` accordingly.

Comment: yes, I have tried this exact piece of code and its caused alot of issues with showing old values. but will see if i can sort it out again.